# It is possible for Client connect to server using different ISP(internet service provider) by ip address and socket port

Tags: java, android, sockets

Just a random question. A thought come into mind if a client are using connection from ISP A and the server using connection from ISP B, it is possible to them to connect successfully through IP address and port only?

Answer (score 1):

The ISP is just the thing which provides internet access for a device/machine, nothing else. After that, the internet is the internet, there is only one. Every server in the internet is reachable by its ip address, each service hosted by one server is reachable by the defined port.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks